# Spring @RequestMapping and trailing slash

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am trying to map a method in a Controller using the annotation with URI template:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/select/{customerNumber}/{resource}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

It appears that this does not get mapped if there is a *trailing slash* at the end of `"resource"`.

**Update:** Using Spring 3.0.2 release

**Update 2:** `@RequestMapping` seems to behave differently for URI templates vs where I don't use template. For non-template, it does not work if I have a trailing slash. But for templates it does not work if I *don't* have a trailing slash. Very strange!

Comment: I am just avoiding using trailing slashes. Thats for now is the way to deal with this behavior. Will investigate more when I have more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 3.0.3 release. [SPR-7064](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7064)